# jquery confirm and exit functionality

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-selectors, jquery-validate

In the html page shown,where is `window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit` code to be placesd so that when validate div is shown the alert message does not appear when the user clicks on cancel or save button.And if the user clicks or any other link the alert message should be shown

If any other link is clicked makeajaxcall() function should be called and then continue

```
    <div id="start" ></div>
    <div id="validate" >
     <input type="button" /value="cancel" onclick="window.locatcation='cancel()'"> 
     <input type="button" /value="save" onclick="save()">
    </div>
   <div id="confirm" ></div>
  <input type="hidden" name="localchanges" id="localchanges" value="1">


   <script>
 function cancel()
 {
 $('lovalchanges').val('0');
  makeajaxcall();
 }

function makeajxcall()
{
     send request to server and get response 
}


$(document).ready({
 if(load_flag == 2)
{
 $("#validate").css({'display':block});
$("#start").css({'display':none});
 $("#confirm").css({'display':none});
  window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit ;
 }
  });
     function confirmExit()
    {
    var ele = document.getElementById ("localchanges") ;
   if (ele.value == "1")
   return "You have not saved any change made . Discard Changes ?" ;
   }

 </script>
```

Comment: Please see the edit in the question

Answer (score 0):

In `$(document).ready()`, your syntax is wrong,

you forgot to write `function()` in `.ready(function (){ .... });`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   if(load_flag == 2) {
     $("#validate").css({'display':'block'});
     $("#start").css({'display':'none'});
     $("#confirm").css({'display':'none'});
     window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit ;
   }
});
```

Comment: There are several more syntax errors here, for example `block` and `none` need to be in quotes, though `.hide()`, `.show()` and combined selectors would be a bit neater.