# window.onbeforeunload functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

When the user click on the OK button before redirecting how to call the delete function and then continue redirecting

```
 $(document).ready({
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit ;

 });

  function confirmExit()
 {
  var ele = document.getElementById ("localchanges") ;
 if (ele.value == "1")
   return "Changes are not saved. Discard changes?" ;
 }



function delete()
{

}
```

Comment: same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793662/jquery-confirm-and-exit-functionality someone merge these pls

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready({
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit ;

 });

  function confirmExit()
 {
 delete()// call delete function here , once this is done , below codes will be executed
  var ele = document.getElementById ("localchanges") ;
 if (ele.value == "1")
   return "Changes are not saved. Discard changes?" ;
 }



function delete()
{

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this ,we can use window.unload as shown.Thanks

```
$(document).ready({
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit ;
 window.onunload = function() { return delete(); }
});

function confirmExit()
{
 var ele = document.getElementById ("localchanges") ;
 if (ele.value == "1")
 return "Changes are not saved. Discard changes?" ;
}



function delete()
{

}
```